# Story Identification Looking for a Harry Potter fic, has demons and m/m. Not a supernatural crossover

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember a bit about it.

Starts with a young Harry Potter.

He has a female friend

His friend commits suicide, I remember the scene was in a bathroom but not much more then that.

He goes to hell and is a pure soul and somehow manages to be adored by the demons and devil.

The demon of    lust or something kisses him goodbye before he leaves and I think the    devil says to him "isn't he a bit young?' And gets a reply like 'I am    the demon of lust' or some such.

The demon can transform into a cat.
I know when they're a bit older, Luna falls for the arch-Angel or    something too.

Pretty sure it was on fanfiction.net with 30-50k+ words.

Teen rating but more likely to have been in the M category.

Read two or three years ago.

Has angels in it too.

I'll put more in and clean this up as I remember more.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it?  The site it was on?  The approximate length?

Comment: Mmh, two or three years ago maybe, and I'm positive it was fanfiction.net and I'm pretty sure it was longer then 50k, but I can't remember if it was completed